# MVC Web App Feature Development Development / production strategies?

Tags: model-view-controller

There is a web app. Let's say I want to add a feature. I can write some code, test it locally, make sure it works - then publish it so it is available to the public. Some features though are very complex and not that easy to be written, tested and shipped the same way.

I want to make it so certain feature I am currently working on is not available to the public even though I publish the app.

Let's say I want to add a custom breadcrumb feature to the app (just for one page to keep it simple). I can write a block of code surrounded by some IsProductionReady variable maintained somewhere in Config file - then once I am done I can set IsProductionReady to True - so now it shows up.

I also want to be able to switch to any other features / changes and publish them without affecting any code, without showing any signs of Breadcrumb feature development. When I am done with the feature I want to be able to just make so it is available to the public.

What are the best practices or strategies to maintain a certain state of a feature? What is the best way to structure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Git, it's better to have a separate branch for each new feature, then after the branch being tested and approved you can merge them into your main develop branch, run another regression test (because different features may interfere each others functionality) and then move it to the Production branch.

Take a look into these urls, I presume you can find your desired scenarios in them :

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow

Answer (score 1):

I would have separate branches on Github between both and keep the structure the same. When your feature is ready, merge to the production branch.

Comment: We use Team Foundation Server - I wonder if there is a way to do that. Good Point Though! I just read how they do it - I like it!